# How to handle array creation with custom JsonSerializerSettings?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I need to create some polymorphic types by using the `$type` property in json so I added custom settings to the deserializer:

```
var jsonSerializerSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
};
```

however now with the setting specified I cannot deserialize arrays anymore and something like this:

```
var arr = (string[])JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@"[ 'foo' ]", jsonSerializerSetting);
```

ends with:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type
>   'System.String[]'

It fails even with the default `new JsonSerializerSettings()`. I guess it must be resetting something but I cannot figure out what.

Can I bring array/list etc creation back and still keep the ability to create the polimorphic types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InvalidCastException` you are seeing has nothing to do with `TypeNameHandling.Auto`.  The problem is that you are not using the [generic version](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1_2.htm) of `DeserializeObject()`.  You need to do:

```
var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string []>(@"[ 'foo' ]", jsonSerializerSetting);
```

The non-generic [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, JsonSerializerSettings)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_1.htm) you are using will indeed return a LINQ-to-JSON [`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) which has no implicit or explicit cast to `string []`.

Comment: wow, thx, this one was too easy ;-) I used the cast before and after I added the settings I was wondering why it doesn't work anymore. I didn't think that it might be actually the generic parameter.